# Logs printing twice in log4j

Tags: java, spring

I developed a module using Spring framework, but i am facing this problem. My module is multi threaded and i have used log4j api for logging.
After few intial logs, it starts printing the logs twice. I think the threadID is getting appended.

Here is a sample log:

> INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:19,725 [localhost-startStop-1][] com.org.test.daoImpl.DBConnection -  DBConnection Successfully Established 
>    INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:19,725 [localhost-startStop-1][] com.org.test.daoImpl.DBConnection -  DB Properties Loaded Successfully
>
> INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:19,902 [localhost-startStop-1][] com.org.test.main.Pusher -  MyClient Successfully Intialized.
>
> INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:20,241 [ActiveMQ Task-1][] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Successfully connected to tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
>
> INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:20,359 [localhost-startStop-1][] org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [JDBC URL = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/myclienttest?autoReconnect=true, Username = myclient, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 1, min (per partition) = 1, idle max age = 60 min, idle test period = 240 min, strategy = DEFAULT] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
>
> INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:20,416 [localhost-startStop-1][] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 3898 ms
>
> Feb 04, 2015 12:45:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>
> INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>
> Feb 04, 2015 12:45:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>
> INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
>
> Feb 04, 2015 12:45:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>
> INFO: Server startup in 14629 ms
>
> INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:20,452 [Thread-5][] com.org.test.queue.QueueSizeBean - RMI MBean Details :: QueueName= queue0  |  #PendingMessages: 0
>
> 3935 [Thread-5] INFO com.org.test.queue.QueueSizeBean  - RMI MBean Details :: QueueName= queue0  |  #PendingMessages: 0
>
> INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:20,453 [Thread-5][] com.org.test.queue.QueueSizeBean - RMI MBean Details :: QueueName= queue1  |  #PendingMessages: 0
>
> 3936 [Thread-5] INFO com.org.test.queue.QueueSizeBean  - RMI MBean Details :: QueueName= queue1  |  #PendingMessages: 0
>
> INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:20,454 [Thread-5][] com.org.test.queue.QueueSizeBean - RMI MBean Details :: QueueName= queue2  |  #PendingMessages: 0
>
> 3937 [Thread-5] INFO com.org.test.queue.QueueSizeBean  - RMI MBean Details :: QueueName= queue2  |  #PendingMessages: 0
>
> INFO 2015-02-04 12:45:24,006 [http-bio-8080-exec-4][] com.org.test.controller.SMSController - URL Hit:: true
>
> 7489 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] INFO com.org.test.controller.Controller  - URL Hit:: true
>
> ...

And these are the log4j property details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="myclient" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/logs.log" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern"
            value="${catalina.base}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}_logs.gz" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.org.test">
    <level value="info" />
    <!-- <appender-ref ref="myclient" /> -->
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <!-- <appender-ref ref="myclient" /> --> 
</root>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have a look here for [Additivity](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat#Additivity).

Comment: May be you should post java code to let us see, how you operate with thread? It is possible that problem is located there.